# How to send a file from ajax to aspnet mvc class

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a file to my aspnet project without using FormData, all the values are sent but the file itself. So I was able to `if ($('#Prop').get(0).files.length === 0` check if theres something in there but I can't send it. The model behind has a `HttpPostedFileBase` property and I was trying to send with :

`$('#Prop').get(0).files`

`$('#Prop').val()`

Not working!

Comment: have you add processData: false, contentType: false in your ajax ?

Comment: Please check **APPROVED SOLUTION**  for file upload only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58877397/mvc-upload-files-from-different-file-inputs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC structure you can use below code:

MVC razar syntax provides **@Ajax.Beginform()**, here you can send "multipart/form-data".

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action", YourController, new { id= Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions {needed options }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" id="fileid" name="filename" />
    <input type="submit" value="Modify" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to send file to controller
in view
function UploadTemplate() {

```
    var filename = $("#ProcessTemplateUpload").val();

    var re = /\..+$/;
    var ext = filename.match(re);

    if (ext == '.xlsx' || ext == '.XLSX' || ext == '.xls' || ext == '.XLS') {

        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $("#ProcessTemplateUpload").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {

            data.append("HelpSection", files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Process/UploadProcessTemplate")',
                type: "Post",
                dataType: "HTML",
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                contentType: false,
                beforeSend: function () { $("#divLoading").show(); },
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#divLoading").hide(); // clear before appending new list

                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert("Uploading Failed Please Select Correct File"); // clear before appending new list
                    $("#Failedrecords").html();
                    $("#divLoading").hide();
                }
            });


        }
    } else {
        alert("Invalid filename, please select another file");
        return false;
    }

}
```

and in controller to access the file
var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSection"];

```
        HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(pic);
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filebase.FileName);
        //var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/upload"), fileName);
        string destination = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "UploadCCIRecovery\\" + fileName;
        string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + destination + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""";
        OleDbConnection myData = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        try
        {

            FileInfo MyFile = new FileInfo(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath);
            DirectoryInfo MyDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "UploadCCIRecovery\\");
            if (MyDirectory.Exists)
            { }
            else
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "UploadCCIRecovery\\");
            }

            if (MyFile.Exists)
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(destination);
                filebase.SaveAs(destination);
            }
            else
            {
                filebase.SaveAs(destination);
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Complete Example,

```html
  <div class="item form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="logo"> Logo <span class="required">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <input id="CouncilLogo" class="  col-md-12 col-xs-12" name="Logo"   type="file"  > </div> <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"> </div>  </div>  <div class="ln_solid"></div>  <div class="form-group"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> <button id="BtnCancel" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button> <button id="BtnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>  </div>  </div>
```

```
<script>
$("#BtnSubmit").click(function () {
var files = $("#Logo").get(0).files; var data = new FormData(); if (files.length > 0) { data.append("file", files[0]); }  $.ajax({ url: "../controllername/SaveImage", type: "Post", data: data,  async: false, contentType: false, processData: false,  success: function (ReturnValue) { if (ReturnValue == "Error") {  alert('Error'); } else {  alert('Success'); } }, error: function (err) {  alert('Something Went Wrong');  }, });
});
</script>
```

Controller code:-

```
 public ActionResult Insert(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string Output = "";
        string ImageName = "";
        try { ImageName = WebImagePath + " Logo/" + 
        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName); }
        catch (Exception e) { }

        if (Output == "")
        {
            try
            {
                string physicalPath = 
              Server.MapPath(ImageName);
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
                objData.CouncilLogo = ImageName;                 

                db.ImageMaster.Add(objData);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Output ="Saved"  
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Output="Error";
            }
        }
        return this.Json(Output);
    }
```